Connecting 3rd party Crash Analytics to Google Play's Crash Analytics
I am new to the Google Play Store Console, and noticed some crashes and ANRs reported in the GP console that I have not seen on my 3rd party crash analytics dashboard. However, Google only reports the crash/ANR stack trace, and I was hoping I could get context around the crash and/or the ANR.
Is there a way I can see full logs for a given crash and what lead up to the report? Or a way I can harvest unique identifiers so I can query for those logs in my 3rd party console?
I saw this post which suggests intercepting all crashes and appending user data to it- this sounds like a TOS violation though... also wouldn't help for ANRs.
My overall goal is to get both system logs and logs lines I create throughout the app (Log.I, Log.W and Log.E).
I see 2 possible solutions to my issue:

If google gives me a way to download the logcat logs surrounding a particular crash, I could get greater context around the crash/ANR
Intercept all crashes, and append these crashes with some unique identifier such that I can query for them in a separate crash dashboard. But then how can I intercept ANRs?

Thanks!
I tried to query based on device type/ android version, but it only narrows my search doesn't help me get particular logs.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What other kind of logs are you looking for? Your logs? System logs?
The play store only provides the crash and nothing else.
Intercepting crash logs with a custom error message is not against TOS, it will however probably provide bad results if not done properly.
If you want to possibly get more information from crashes then might I suggest Firebase Crashlytics where you have the ability to slightly customize crash reports

I've updated the post with more details about my question

@ordinary_puddle you cannot get the system logs, your best and really only option is using firebase crashlytics or your own custom logging implementation
